# ADO Recordset->EndOfFile giving me _com_error when Empty Recordset

Tags: c++, com, ado

I'm using ADO, and getting a very weird com error.

So I'm simply running a stored proc using ADO CommandPtr, and storing it in a Recordset.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
_ConnectionPtr Connptr;
//Instantiate ConnectionPtr...

_CommapndPtr CommPtr;
CommPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
CommPtr->CommandType = adCmdText;
CommPtr->ActiveConnection = ConnPtr;
CommPtr->CommandText = "Execute MyDb..MyStoredProc";

_RecordsetPtr RecPtr;
RecPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
RecPtr->CursorLocation = adUseClient;
RecPtr->CacheSize = 150;

RecPtr = CommPtr->Execute(NULL, NULL, adOptionUnspecified);   //RecPtr = Empty Recordset

while (!RecPtr->EndOfFile) {       //ERROR HAPPENS HERE!!!
    //Do something
    RecPtr->MoveNext();
}
```

So my stored procedure is supposed to returns an empty recordset (0 rows).

But then , when I check if the recordset has reached the end (which should simply return true if it is empty). I get a com error.

When I caught the com error and printed it out, I got this.

```
Code = -2147217849
Meaning = IDispatch error #3153
Source = NULL
```

Which doesn't tell me much.

I don't understand why `RecPtr->EndofFile` is throwing a com error, since it should simply return true/false.

I highly doubt that the error is caused because I'm doing something wrong when initializing Connection and Command objects. (If so, then I would have gotten the error when Executing the command.)

Any ideas on what might be causing this exception?

Comment: Rock solid error handling is *very* important when you use ADO.  There are a gazillion things that can go wrong in a dbase engine, as well as in your own code when you don't use it properly.  If you don't get the error reporting right then you'll have a very hard time.  The actual error you are getting is ADO error 3655, "Invalid storage location".  How that got mangled to error 3153 is impossible to explain.

Comment: You know that recordset you worked so hard to set up for client side cursors is completely thrown out with that connection-based call to `Execute` . Right?

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm sorry,, I didn't understand.. what do you mean by "completely thrown out"? Am I using the recordptr in a wrong way?

Comment: I mean `RecPtr = ...` will throw out the recordset object you just prepared for client side cursors. The is a specific format needed for using the `Open` method of a recordset in conjunction with a `Command` object with the active connection set to utilize the settings you're configuring to the created (not returned) `RecPtr` interface. Do a little digging. I'm overloaded @ work right now but if I have time tonight I'll try and post something.

Comment: @HansPassant How do you know if the actual error is 3655,,?

Comment: -2147217849 == 0x80040E47, 0xE47 == 3655.  Which is a valid ADO error code, 3153 is not.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh wow, thanks.. I can't find any information on error code 3655 ... do you have any reference or link which tells at least why may be caused?