# ADO Error: "Operation Cannot be Performed While Executing Asynchronously"

Tags: c++, sybase, ado

I posted a similar question before,, but now I'm getting a different error.

I am using ADO Command object to execute a simple query and store the result in a Recordset Object..

(someone mentioned before that I can use ConnectionPtr->Execute or Recordset->Open method instead,, but there's a specific reason why I'm using the ADO Command object..)

Anyways this is a summary of my code:

```
_ConnectionPtr Connptr;
//Instantiate ConnectionPtr...

_CommapndPtr CommPtr;
CommPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
CommPtr->CommandType = adCmdText;
CommPtr->ActiveConnection = ConnPtr;
CommPtr->CommandText = "Execute MyDb..MyStoredProc";

_RecordsetPtr RecPtr;
RecPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
RecPtr->CursorLocation = adUseClient;
RecPtr->CacheSize = 150;

RecPtr = CommPtr->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText); 

while (!RecPtr->EndOfFile) {       //ERROR HAPPENS HERE!!!
    //Do something
    RecPtr->MoveNext();
}
```

When I try to check if Recordset is empty,, I get this _com_error exception:

```
Code = -2146824577
Meaning = Unknown error 0x800A0E7F
Source = ADODB.Command
Description = Operation cannot be performed while executing asynchronously
```

I found this strange,, because I'm not using adAsyncExec option when Executing the Command object.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Sigh, hard to guess what could have produced "_CommapndPtr".  It is really rather important that you post *real* code, not some cleaned up version of what is actually a big mess.  It is a "big mess" kind of error.  With over 30,000 Google hits, you have to do the leg work first.

Comment: The "someone" who mentioned using `RecPtr->Open` (and said nothing about alternatively using `ConnPtr->Execute`; in fact, I said you should *not* be using `Execute`), [**was me**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017995/ado-recordset-endoffile-giving-me-com-error-when-empty-recordset#comment38913887_25017995). Properly setting up a modified recordset open from a store proc via a command object requires special calling of the `Open` method of the recrodset object, passing the command object (properly wired to your connection) as the Source parameter.